# How to find out who removed a line of code in a branch?

Tags: mercurial, blame

We're getting an error in one of our branches in deployment and looking at it I see that one file is missing a line of code. How do I find out who removed it and when?

I know this has something to do with hg blame, but seems every time I try to use it I get a "this file does not exist in this commit" message, and even then I'm not sure how to formulate the query to give me what I want.

Answer (score 3):

If you know *at least part* of string, you can use `hg grep -all -u "STRING" filename` (-u will show username, associated with changeset)

```
>hg grep --all -u "load_theme_textdomain" functions.php
functions.php:2:-:lazybadger:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
functions.php:2:+:lazybadger:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
functions.php:1:+:lazybadger:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
```

transcript: string was added in changeset 1 ("1:+:") and edited in changeset 2 (":2:-:" + "2:+:") by user with username in field 4 of output. Removed line will not have `:+:` in last chronologically (first in output) changeset in history

Answer (score 1):

Ok I admit that you use mercurial for your versionning, and the command for what you want is

```
 hg annotate -u
```

it's an alias for blame
and well, it's pretty simple : hg annotate -u *yourFile* and that's it...

Comment: Right I understand that but how do I use this to know who *deleted* a line?

Comment: Ohh in that case 'hg grep'

hg grep will let you search a change log for a pattern, such as a deleted string. If you are looking for more than just the first occurrence, be sure to include the --all flag. It looked something like this:

hg grep --all -r 9876:tip "pattern" path/to/file

Comment: what pattern? and what's the revspec that you specified here?

Comment: the documentation will explain it better than me with my poor english :P http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html

but the pattern is a python's regexp of what the deleted line (to get the name of the author after)

Comment: I had to get offline but I see what you're getting at. This might work given certain circumstances but isn't really the final answer. For example if that same line appeared and disappeared many times or if you're looking for the latest time it happened across multiple branches. I think there must be something like this with blame/annotate.